# Remove "file:" from a path in cmd batch file

Tags: batch-file

I used to use an addon for Firefox that would let me open an html file, on my system, in an external editor. The ones "built in" are for testing, and don't let you update the "local" copy and the existing addon only opens things in other browsers. So.. I decided to try to use a batch file to handle this. This is the code I am trying to test this with:

```
cls
set str=%1:~8%
echo. %str%
```

This is an example of what Firefox ends up passing to the batch file:

file:///C:/Users/Patrick/Documents/Comics.html

The expected result is that str becomes C:/Users/Patrick/Documents/Comics.html and I can then pass that, via the batch file, to the editor.

This is what I get instead:

```
C:\Users\~\Desktop>set str=file:///C:/Users/Patrick/Documents/Comics.html:~8

C:\Users\~\Desktop>echo. file:///C:/Users/Patrick/Documents/Comics.html:~8
 file:///C:/Users/Patrick/Documents/Comics.html:~8
```

I have also tried to set the str variable "to" %1, then use "set str=%str:~8%", but that just gives me ":~8". I think I accidentally stumbled over one version that was giving me "C:/Users/Patrick/Documents/Comics.html:~8", but.. yeah, that wasn't even close to right either, and I think it was somehow ignoring one of the "set" functions and just making the resulting string short, each time I run the batch...

I have no freaking clue what is going wrong here, unless there is some bloody stupid issue with the extra : in there, as part of the string.

I also thought about using powershell instead, but.. I would have to tell my system to allow that to execute, and that creates a potential security hole.

In any case.. Is there actually some way to manage this, or is the existence of the file:\\ thing in there just not only make my editor refuse to load it, but also make the batch file refuse to work, at all?

Comment: Why are you using `:~8%` in this assignment?

Comment: You can only manipulate an environmental variable.  You cannot manipulate command line arguments or `FOR` meta-variables.  So you have to use the `SET` command to assign the command line argument to a variable first: `set str=%~1`.  Then you can use the sub string method to remove the first 8 characters: `set str=%str:~8%`.

Comment: Hmm... Ok, that, almost, works.. I get: "C:/Users/~/Documents/Comics.html:~8" doing that. For some incomprehensible reason it not only removes the part of the string that I want, but it appends the actual argument being used to define what to skip to the end. I don't get why its doing that...

Comment: @PatrickElliott, if you are getting a tilde and 8 at the end of your output then you hard coded there.

Comment: Meaning? Because, based on the examples, it isn't supposed to do that.

Comment: Oh.. WTF.. lol Turns out the problem is "spacing" The first "set" users set str<no space>=<no space>%~1, the second one used set str<space>=<space>... This, somehow, created two different variables, and caused some sort of very odd quirk in what result it returned, when it tried to shorten the string. Simply removing the bloody spaces in the one line makes it work perfectly.. o.O

Comment: None of your code examples showed spaces before or after the equals symbol.  Batch files are not very free form.  If you read the help file, the syntax for the `SET` command you will see there are no spaces in the syntax example.  Going forward please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can only manipulate an environmental variable. You cannot manipulate command line arguments or FOR meta-variables. So you have to use the SET command to assign the command line argument to a variable first. Then you can use the sub string method to remove the first 8 characters.

So given the following code.

```
@echo off
set str=%~1
echo Input: %str%
set str=%str:~8%
echo Output: %str%
```

Now if we run the batch file and use your given example as the command line argument to the batch file.  It will look like this.

```
C:\Batch\SO>foo.bat file:///C:/Users/Patrick/Documents/Comics.html
Input: file:///C:/Users/Patrick/Documents/Comics.html
Output: C:/Users/Patrick/Documents/Comics.html

C:\Batch\SO>
```

One other option would be to just do string replacement.

```
@echo off
set str=%~1
set str=%str:*file:///=%
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I tried the string replacement one too, but.. guessing it failed both due to a) not using *, like you did there, and b) for the same reason mine was driving me nuts. The extra bloody spaces around the equal signs. Very weird. I had no idea batch was so picky about "that" specific issue. But, at least I got ti to work now. I got tired of using drop downs, or the like to track new forums/comics I read every day, so use simple html pages, so its load the page, click each link, then return, instead. Then.. Mozilla killed adding things to their context menu, and..

Comment: Just wish I could fix the freaking, "No, I do not want the option to bloody open in a new "windows" from the freaking menu, like I could back when they actually let you edit the menu contents. This, "You can't open than in an editor" thing has been driving me nuts for months, and decided I "needed" to solve it tonight, even if everything else I used to change is still broken. lol But, thanks again for the help.

Comment: @PatrickElliott You actually don't need the asterisk for the string replacement if you absolutely know that the string you want to remove only appears once within your variable.  It is just a trick to keep it from only replacing it once in the string at the beginning as it is non greedy.